# ImportError: No module named selenium windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, importerror

Yesterday I began using selenium with python 3.8. It was all working well with no errors. However, when I tried to run the exact same piece of code today, I got the error: ImportError: No module named selenium. I haven't deleted or installed anything new since I ran it yesterday, I have tried uninstall and installing python, pip and selenium. I have tried running it on multiple different versions of python (3.6,3.7,3.8,2.7) all with the according selenium version. Nothing is working. The cmd prompt tells me requirement already satisfied when I type pip install selenium. Any advice? I am on Windows 10 using the chrome driver,

Comment: Did you add anything to your PATH variables?

Answer (score 0):

For which environment you need to check first.

If you have installed `pip`. Then check first `pip --version`. This will give you the version of python which pip pointing to.

Then you need to run your application using that python(3.6 or, 3.7 or 2.7) for selenium. Because you must have used `pip install selenium`

But the Best way to use any custom library in python is virtual environment. That will avoid conflict.

For Reference,

[Pip install problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61289734/pip-install-problems/61289814#61289814)

You can install virtual environment like this.